# javascript xml reader

Tags: javascript, xml

I will keep this very short:
I'm trying to make a loop through an xml-document for a gallery. I got a script that should work, but doesn't. Can anyone please tell me where I did wrong?

I didn't want to make this longer because the problem is simple and have been pondering over this since yesterday and this is the closest I get.

I want to loop through the xml-file and print out "path" and "file" first and most. I'm building a gallery and thought that the best way to save all the data for the images was an xml-file, but now I can't get it to loop correctly. In the script I made the page print out both x and i, which resulted with x being 1 and i being 0, hence it hasn't worked through the for-loop at all as I see it.

Any help would be appreciated, because I'm stuck. Been trying so many solutions that my head is spinning and I can't get any further without a nudge in the right direction.

The html/javascript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function displayResult()
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","../gallery/gallery.xml",false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


                x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("session");
                for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                { 
                    img = "<img src='";
                    path = (x[0].getElementsByTagName("path")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    file = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("file")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    end = "' /><br />";
                    name = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    txt = "x:" + x.length + "| i " + i + "<br />" + img + path + file + end + name + "<br />";
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = txt;
                    //document.write(txt);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayResult()">
        <div id='content'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

xml-file:

```
<gallery>
    <session>
        <path>../gallery/beauty/</path>
        <item>
            <file>_DSC2331.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 1</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <file>_DSC2339.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 2</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <file>_DSC2350.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 3</name>
        </item>
        <date>2011-08-03</date>
    </session>
</gallery>
```

Comment: This is a bit *too* short.  Could you give any more direction? maybe any errors or weird behavior? it's unlikely you will get a lot of attention saying, "fix my code".

What does this do?

Comment: Not sure what happens and what do you expect instead ?

Comment: You'll have to tell us how it's not working. Does the XHR not work? Do the getElementsByTagName searches not work? Does the content update not work?

Comment: Recently updated so you perhaps get a better idea of what I'm trying to do. Sorry for being a bit short in explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can make some suggestions:

1. Use the `var` keyword within functions to make those variables local to that function. The code you have at the moment would set values in the global namespace, which is often considered bad practice (e.g. you could overwrite other people's variables, or other people could overwrite yours). Also declare your variables at the start of a function, as they will be [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) there anyway.
2. Split your code up into more meaningful functions. This way they become easier to read and often then become more reusable.
3. Make sure you loop through `items` as well as `sessions`.
4. Consider using a Javascript framework like [jQuery](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://jquery.com/&rct=j&q=jquery&ei=kqBqTtGhD8mr8QP3p-gr&usg=AFQjCNFA7CZ5sWRDhHPuipmhL7zVksjC2A&sig2=TAp_gSkJiBxl-l6dfB9zhw&cad=rja). They can often simplify the code you have to write, and you will usually end up writing less code yourself.

.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadDoc(url) {
                var xmlhttp = null;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return xmlhttp.responseXML;
            }

            function getContent(sessions) {
                var items = null,
                    i = 0,
                    j = 0,
                    img = "",
                    path = "",
                    file = "",
                    end = "",
                    name = "",
                    txt = "";
                for (i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) { 
                    items = sessions[i].getElementsByTagName("item");
                    path = sessions[i].getElementsByTagName("path")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                        img = "<img src='";
                        file = items[j].getElementsByTagName("file")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        end = "' /><br />";
                        name = items[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        txt += "session[" + i + "] item[" + j + "]<br />" + img + path + file + end + name + "<br />";
                    }
                }
                return txt;
            }

            function displayResult()
            {
                var xmlDoc = loadDoc("../gallery/gallery.xml");
                var sessions = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("session");
                var txt = getContent(sessions);
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = txt;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayResult()">
        <div id='content'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I think I gained a level in javascript thanks to you. I shall ponder over this code with ease now when I don't have to brood over it any more. Again; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that you want to show all items.

Yet you loop over 'session', of which there is only one.

So at best you will get only 1 picture this way..

You probably want to loop over `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item")` and still use the session one to have access to the path.

Comment: x is still greater then i so it should keep counting upwards and search all the child-nodes anyway. But it's stuck on 0. I shall look into what you said though and see if it can lead me somewhere. It's just confusing why it won't count upwards since I ask it to print x and i on the screen.

Comment: As @tomdemuyt has said, x.length==1 as you are looping through the `<session>` elements.

Comment: But i is equal 0 still, so it doesn't go up. Or am I'm thinking in the wrong way here?

Comment: And everything disappears when I'm selecting the <item>-element instead. Any good ideas of how to rebuild it? I am very new to xml, perhaps I should have added that. :)