# Combining php $_GET[''] with Javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am currently coding a gallery which until now has been combining AJAX and Javascript with an xml-file to load all images. Now I have come to the fun part where I click an image to enter the inner gallery. (On the first page they load one image of each session and when one image is pressed it will continue to the rest of the images of that session.)

The problem that I have with AJAX (I'm sure there is a neat hack for this as well!) is that when the page is reloaded it automatic goes back to the session index since there is no URL-change.

What I have done now, so far is to put one javascript-function in one document where it loads only the gallery index. This works flawless.

In the other file I got just about the same code, but instead it loads the function that loads the rest of the session-images, but I don't get it to work.

Here is the script that should load the specific session-images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = displayGallery(<?php echo $_GET['session']; ?>);
</script>

<div id="gallery">

</div>
```

When I just only javascript and an "onload" in the link it worked just fine, but then I had the problem to reload the page. Now I just php to include this file and $_GET the variable for "displayGallery()"

```
function displayGallery(sessionAtt)
```

So in an attempt to make this clear, I'm rubbish explaining stuff, I need help with making the displayGallery(sessionAtt) actually run after grabbing the essential variable from the url.

I am VERY fresh on Javascript. Done most scripts in php up until now.

**EDIT:**

To explain the site a bit: It's a gallery I'm making for a friend of mine. There is no login for anyone else but her and all sub-pages (Start, Gallery, About, etc.) is loaded through php "include".

The XML:

```
<gallery>
    <session>
        <sessionName>Beauty</sessionName>
        <path>gallery/beauty/</path>
        <item>
            <file>_DSC2331.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 1</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <file>_DSC2339.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 2</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <file>_DSC2350.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 3</name>
        </item>
        <date>2011-08-03</date>
    </session>
    <session>
        <sessionName>Red</sessionName>
        <path>gallery/red/</path>
        <item>
            <file>_MG_6227-web.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 1</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <file>_MG_6235-web.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 2</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <file>_MG_6240-cropped-web.jpg</file>
            <name>Picture 3</name>
        </item>
        <date>2011-08-03</date>
    </session>
</gallery>
```

The js:

```
function displayGallery(sessionAtt)
{
    var xmlDoc = loadDoc("gallery/gallery.xml");
    var sessions = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("session");
    var txt = getGallery(sessions, sessionAtt);
    document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = txt;
}

function getGallery(sessions, sessionAtt) {
    var items = null,
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    sessionName = "",
    link = "",
    img = "",
    path = "",
    file = "",
    txt = "";
    for (i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) { 
        sessionName = sessions[i].getElementsByTagName("sessionName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        if(sessionName == sessionAtt)
        {
            items = sessions[i].getElementsByTagName("item");
            path = sessions[i].getElementsByTagName("path")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                file = items[j].getElementsByTagName("file")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                link = '<a href="' + path + file + '" rel="lightbox[' + sessionName + ']" title="' + sessionName + '">';
                img = '<img src="' + path + file + '" class="thumb" onclick="displayImage();" /></a>';
                txt += link + img;
            }
        }
    }
    return txt;
}
```

I have tried to run the script with sessionAtt set in the function and it works.

```
window.onload = displayGallery;
```

But when changing it to

```
window.onload = displayGallery('Red');
```

both manually and with php... Nothing.

Comment: What do you mean combining "AJAX and Javascript"? AJAX *is* Javascript (Asynchronous Javascript And XML)

Comment: What I really wanted to get through what methods I used. AJAX to get the xml-file and Javascript for everything else. I know they are the same, it was just a bad explanation from my part. :)

Comment: I think I understand what you want to achieve, but I'm a little confused as to _how_ you're trying to achieve it. When you say "AJAX", what exactly do you mean? The code you're showing here isn't really AJAX and when you use AJAX the page shouldn't be reloaded.

Comment: I played around a bit with a script I got from a previous question I asked, which is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367460/javascript-xml-reader/7368491#7368491

Comment: if you echo $_GET['session'] do you get anything?

Comment: David: It gives me the correct value, but doesn't load any images. I have tried the variable in the source-script to see if everything works which it does. But now when I put it to action in the page, nothing. Robin: Yep, both ' and ". Both returns nothing.

Comment: Are all the sessions in the same XML file? In the previous question, you only show one session and the Javascript code shows all items in that session.

Comment: Yes, all sessions are in the same xml-file. All sessions got a tag named <sessionName>. It's the sessionName I need to have compared with the variable I'm trying to store in the function. I have only posted a small part of the code, I will update with a few examples so you can see better what I've done.

Comment: Even when loading the first piece of code that I printed with php "include"? Everything worked for my up to the point when I have to transfer the variable from window.onload = displayGallery('Red'); to function displayGallery(sessionAtt)
{...

Comment: I'd propose to have a look at xajax here: http://www.xajax-project.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine for me. The only thing I did differently is I used `<body onload="displayGallery('Red')">` rather than `window.onload = displayGallery('Red');`

As Martin pointed out, using `window.onload` tries to find `<div id='gallery'>` *before* the page is loaded, giving an error: **document.getElementById("gallery") is null**

Using `<body onload="displayGallery('Red')">` waits for the page to finish loading before calling displayGallery.

Comment: Which actually gave me the solution! I can't use <body onload=""> since I load pages in php, which means everything would collide if I put it in body. But instead I put the <script> under the gallery-div so it would load after it read everything else and then could find the correct div. :) I tried it out and it worked.

Comment: @Richard: Good thinking. I don't know why I didn't think of it. :-p

Comment: Don't know what time it is at your place, but here it's 02:15 in the night. It is allowed not to think of everything then. :)

Comment: @Richard: It's only 8:30 here so I don't really have an excuse. :) You're doing well with Javascript. I commend you. If I may, I'd like to suggest that you look into jQuery. It makes AJAX a whole lot easier and you can use a ton of plug-ins for things like lightbox, fades, carousels, and so much more.

Comment: I have looked a bit on jQuery and I actually am using lightbox on my site. Works like a charm so far. And thank you for the commendation and for the help. It is said that one learns something new every day. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood what you are trying to do. But try these things.

**. make a javascript variable that will hold the value of GET['session']. and later use that variable. its also easier for debugging.

**. insdead of window.onload make a function call it 'init' and in the body tag write:

```
<head>
 <script>
   function init(){
     //displaying gallery or other stuff
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
```

this ensures that your script runs after the page was loaded.

** If I got you right, there is a session for each user. and in this case (as a rule of thumb) at the very top of your php file, even before the

```
session_start();
```

Comment: No user and I can't have it in the body-tag since I load all sub-pages with php "include("");".

Comment: What I think the OP means by "session" is a gallery session (for example: different models). At least that's what I got from it.

Comment: The problem still stands about the variable in the function that I need to pass on when the page loads. I want people to be able to press reload without walking from the root to the session they are at. (Two or three clicks, but annoying enough for some.) That's why I have to get the session-name from the url and add it to the javascript-function. Can jQuery work? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your description several times...

1) GET variables only work if you provide variables in the URL for eg. index.php?session=model1

2) You're saying that the back button doesn't work because the page doesn't change, which is wrong if you are using get variables correctly

Your index page should be linking to each session page like so: `<a href="gallery.php?session=modela">` only then can you use the javascript to pull the variable on the gallery.php

Comment: Once again I explained things poorly and I'm sorry for that. I am using ?session=something to get "something" (for example) for the url. And it's not the back-button that is the problem (since I haven't even created one yet.) The problem is that everything in the gallery is loaded with javascript so the url stays the same. I need to run "displayGallery(<?php $_GET['session'] ?>);", but that doesn't want to work. I got "session" in the url.

Comment: Get variables only work with changing URLs, you have to reload the page to change a page via GET. You'll have ot use Javascript variables if you want things to change in page.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you should use XSLT instead of what you do...mark it as WIKI as it does not answer your specific question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.onload = displayGallery(<?php echo $_GET['session']; ?>);`

Use

```
window.onload = function() {
    displayGallery(<?php echo "'" . $_GET['session'] . "'"; ?>);
};
```

As you said, assigning the function like `window.onload = displayGallery;` works. When assigning it like `window.onload = displayGallery('Red');`, what is happening is that the function is not being attached to `window.onload`, but what it *returns* is. And the function returns nothing, so `window.onload = undefined;`.

This also explains why nothing happens, because the function is not being called on onload, but as soon as the browser executes the script.

The way I've fixed this is by assigning a function without executing it (`window.onload = function() { ... }`), and placed the function which you *are* executing within it.

Comment: Seems valid, but for knowledge sake; why? :)

Comment: Well as you said, assigning the function like `window.onload = displayGallery;` works. When assigning it like `window.onload = displayGallery('Red');` what is happening is that the function is not being attached to `window.onload`, what it *returns* is. And the function returns nothing, so `window.onload = undefined;`. This also explains why nothing happens, because the function is not being called on `onload`, but as soon as the browser executes the script.

Comment: I should also point out that I wrapped what you're echoing with PHP in quotation marks - important to remember.

Comment: I otherwise solved the problem by moving the script under the div, so the div is created before the script since the script is looking for that div to insert the code. Thanks anyway and I shall remember your advice in case I run into more trouble. :)

Comment: No worries :) I put the explanation in the answer too